# Common files between multiple GWT pages

Tags: java, gwt

I want to design multiple pages using google web toolkit, reading one of the previous answers [GWT multi modules for separate HTML pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898595/gwt-multi-modules-for-seperate-html-pages) suggests that they way to do this is to have multiple modules. Hence I made 2 modules in my GWT application. They compile and run fine but however I find that each has its own folder in the war directory after compilation. Some of the files like UI image components that GWT generates are shared between the 2 modules. I was wondering if there was a way to have it organized that only 1 copy of such files is produced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you're said I can only assume you're using the Image widget and given the referenced post, that you might be using an older version of GWT.

I've worked with GWT 2.1 extensively and not knowing what you're trying to do it might be a worthwhile to check out these out:

- [Declarative Layout](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html) - to design multiple pages (Check out @UiTemplate)
- [ClientBundle](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html) - (See ImageResource)

Depending on the size of the images, you can use this approach to reduce the number of trips to the server by either using image sprites or in-lining it altogether. (Note: IE8 has an in-lining ("data:") has a size limitation of 32KB).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you concerned with the *generated* UI Image components being duplicated? What problem are you trying to solve here?
For all image components which *you* supply, you can always put them under war/images and they will be shared.

Comment: but then I have no way to update image paths in the javascript that GWT images. The image paths dont appear in my java code as those are GWT generated images and stuff.

Comment: You don't update the javascript that GWT generates. You update them in your code.